# Multiple render variants with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a web application using React which is up and running and working well. I should probably just leave it alone, but there's one area which is troubling me, where I think I need to do a bit of refactoring because what I'm doing doesn't seem to me to be going with the flow of React. I'd be interested in others' views.

I have a React class, Product, which I use to keep track of products on the page. The only property stored in state is 'quantity', but I have various functions which do things like update a basket by means of pub/sub. Depending on how and where this Product class is used (whether in a table or for a detail view, whether on mobile or desktop), the necessary display is quite different. So in my render function, I call variously 'renderForDetailOnMobile', 'renderForTableOnMobile', 'renderForDetailOnDesktop' and 'renderForTableOnDesktop'.

As I say, this doesn't feel very React-y to me, as if I've got the whole thing upside down (although the rest of the app is, I would say much more idiomatic). So how should be thinking this through in order to break it down into separate smaller classes, which is what I imagine I should be doing? Sorry, for privacy reasons it's not possible to poast actual code, so I hope this description makes the situation clear enough.

Comment: Sometimes, a piece of code is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using reducers or stores, depending whether you have a flux or redux application. This would help you to understand your state and how it changes.

I see you are using state in your `Product`, while you should be using stores as mentioned above.

So, how I see the issue is that you have data source and you need to transform it based on the device requirements.

In such case I would make a container which would load other components in charge of transforming and presenting data for different devices.
Container should be rather simple just returning the correct component based on the conditional being met.